# Uncaught TypeError: this.save is not a function (VueJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to call the function **save** after I make sure the image is completely loaded, but it does not work!

In `<script>`:

```
//change image width and heignt (100*100).
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var width = 100; var height = 100;
canvas.width = 100; canvas.height = 100;
var imgTile = new Image(); imgTile.src = this.cropImg;
imgTile.onload = function(){
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imgTile, 0, 0, width, height);
  var img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  console.log("img_data: " + img_data);
  this.New_cropImg = img_data;
  this.showImage = true;
  this.save(this.New_cropImg);
};
```

and function save is already defined and works perfectly outside the **onload** function.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is because "this.save" is invoked from the context of imgTile. I think you should call save without "this" and make sure it is hoisted before the onload is invoked

Comment: @BenFortune I didn't find anything there to help me, I am using VueJs to implement the code, not pure javascript. save function is defined in the method section, and even the method that I call save function from it it is defined there.

Comment: @SumodhNair I tried to remove `this` and run the code, it said `Uncaught ReferenceError: save is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is (as stated in the comments) that your context within the function is wrong

```
imgTile.onload = function(){
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imgTile, 0, 0, width, height);
  var img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  console.log("img_data: " + img_data);
  this.New_cropImg = img_data;
  this.showImage = true;
  this.save(this.New_cropImg);
}.bind(this);
```

a simple `.bind(this)` can solve it for you.

Comment: Thanks bro, it's work ;)